# How to select the user that has max number of entries?

Tags: mysql, sql

Can you help me to come up with a query to show the user with maximum number of entries.

[image]

This should show "Benedicto Dalondonan" since he has the most number of request.

Thanks guys.

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: actually I had no idea, I can only count the max.

Answer (score 3):

you can do this using

```
select requestor,count(req_id) 
from table_name 
group by requestor 
order by count(req_id) desc limit 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, but my goal is to show only the name with the max number of entries,

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select * from `table` group by requestor having max(count(*))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT requester, COUNT(*) as c 
FROM table GROUP BY requester
having max(count(*))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT requestor,count(req_id)total
FROM table_name
GROUP BY requestor
HAVING MAX(COUNT(*))
ORDER BY count(req_id) desc limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just little tweak

```
SELECT name 
FROM  (SELECT Count(*) AS cnt, name 
       FROM   `test` 
       GROUP  BY name 
       ORDER  BY cnt DESC 
       LIMIT  1) AS test;
```